# Delete line if a pattern is not there

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file with MAC addresses and port numbers like this:

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff 1/1
aa:ff:00:55:66:99 1/1
00:11:22:33:44:55 1/1
99:88:77:66:55:44 1/1
ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa 1/2
```

How can I delete all the lines that have the port number 1/1 AND where the MAC is not aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you invert the condition and think of it as *matching* instead of *deleting*, you can use `awk` to print out matching lines:

```
awk '$1 == "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff" || $2 != "1/1"' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this `sed` one-liner:

```
sed '/aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff/b; /1\/1/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` and `sed` solutions are very elegant and efficient. For completeness, if the order does not matter, you could also use two `grep`:

```bash
$ grep '^aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff' file; grep -Ev '(^aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff| 1/1$)' file
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff 1/1
ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa 1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {m,g}awk '_<$+2 != NF%+2' FS='^aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff |1[/]1$'
> ```

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff 1/1
ff:ee:dd:cc:bb:aa 1/2
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Tyler2P : how is ONE single modulo of 2 confusing ?

Comment: @Tyler2P : that should cover the hidden bug that wasn't part of the sample test set

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: The issue is that future readers who are new to the language may be unfamiliar with the syntax or the particular calls. Adding an explanation helps them understand what you’re doing, and makes your answer more useful. If you could [edit] it to offer that explanation, it would be much appreciated by those future readers.

Comment: @JeremyCaney : anyone who has bothered to read OP's original question would instantly understand what mine was doing.  and what "calls" are you referring to, considering the fact that mine didn't make a single function call at all

Comment: Both @Tyler2P and I are just trying to help you improve your answer. It’s obviously up to you if you want to take our advice, or think it’s worth your time. Typically, answers with more explanation get more upvotes over time, if that’s of value to you.